# Can I convert a library font into a sprite sheet in AS3?

Tags: actionscript-3, fonts, rendering

In Flash I am able to create a font asset and add it to the library:

[image]

I want to convert this asset into some `BitmapData` that will contain all of the characters with the correct letter spacing/line height etc.

Is there an inbuilt way of doing this other than manually creating text fields, adding a character, using `BitmapData.draw()` and then adding the result to a sprite sheet?

If I need to do it manually like above, is there a way to retrieve all of the embedded characters? For example, in the above screenshot I'd expect only `a-z`, `A-Z`. Or will I need to note these manually as well?

Comment: I once did a similar thing, all I did was wrote an AIR app that place a single textfield with centered alignment on the stage and made it run a loop of populating the text field with a single character, drawing the stage to a bitmap, then saving it to a PNG and repeat. You could then use an app like Texture Packer (http://www.texturepacker.com/) and create a sprite sheet from your batch of png's.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're going to go with your own solution as I mentioned in my comment (like drawing out each supported character and then batching them together) then here is how you can look up every possible glyph supported by the embedded font. (Psuedo Code)

```
//Build out a loop that will generate char codes for all possible glyphs
for(etc, etc, etc) {
   String glyph = String.fromCharCode(%26);
   if(myFont.hasGlyphs(glyph) == true) {
      myTextField.text = glyph;
      myBitmap.draw(myTextField);
      //Save image and repeat
   }
}
```

Reference material:
[List of supported char codes](http://allwebco-templates.com/support/S_hex.htm). 
[Font.hasGlyphs() documentation.](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/text/Font.html#hasGlyphs%28%29)
[String.fromCharCode() documentation.](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/String.html#fromCharCode%28%29)